# Что за конструкция

Tags: python, python-3.x

Что за конструкция
`{i[0]: i[1] for i in pricesale}`

в частности что даёт  `i[0]: i[1]` перед `for`

Comment: Dict comprehension. Создает словарь с ключами i[0] и значениями i[1] для всех i в pricesale

Answer (score 6):

в списке `pricesale` содержатся некоторые списки или кортежи, содержащие минимум 2 элемента

через `{}` формируется словарь, где каждый элемент списка `pricesale` превращается в элемент словаря - ключ `i[0]` и значение `i[1]`

Пример:

```
pricesale = [('носки', 100), ('трусы', 200, 'а это значение использоваться не будет')]

res = {i[0]: i[1] for i in pricesale}

print(res)
```

будет выведено:

```
{
    'носки': 100, 
    'трусы': 200
}
```